# Where is the location that gradle downloads dependency in Android Studio？

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Where is the location that gradle downloads dependency in Android Studio?

How to find them?

Answer (score 26):

With my setup, I can find the files at the following location:

**~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/**

For example, Picasso artifacts were downloaded at the following location on Mac:
*emphasized text*/Users/**USER_NAME**/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.picasso/picasso/

This folder has three directories for .pom file, sources, and actual jar file.

This is not in project specific .gradle folder but is in the global .gradle cache instead.

Comment: The path on Windows machine is as follows: WINDOWS_DRIVE:\Users\YOUR_USER.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1

Comment: '~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/' is true for mac

Answer (score 0):

In my case the modules on which my app depend are downloaded to the project folder, alongside my app folder.

```
project_folder
|-app
|-module_1
|-module_2
|-...
```